# Organizing messages in user chat activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout

i have created a custom view holder for my app to position sent messages to the right and received messages to the left which is working.

when messages are sent or received they are positioned as expected but when the chat activity is closed and reopened both the sent and received messages are positioned to the left and given the same color.

how can i make it remain as it is even when the app is closed and reopened?

below is my `MessageAdapter.java`

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


private Context mContext;
private List<Messages> mMessageList;

public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> mMessageList) {
    //mContext = context;

    this.mMessageList = mMessageList;

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessageList.size();
}

// Determines the appropriate ViewType according to the sender of the message.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    Messages c = mMessageList.get(i);

    String from_user = c.getFrom();
    String message_type = c.getType();


    if (from_user == (current_user_id)) {

        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;

    } else {

        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
    }
}

    // Inflates the appropriate layout according to the ViewType.
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
        View view;

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, false);
            return new SentMessageHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, false);
            return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
        }

        return null;
    }


    // Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        Messages c = mMessageList.get(i);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
                ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(c);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(c);
        }
    }

    private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageText, timeText;

        SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            messageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
            timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        }

        void bind(Messages message) {
            messageText.setText(message.getMessage());

            // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
          //  timeText.setText(Utils.formatDateTime(message.getCreatedAt()));
        }
    }

    private class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;
        ImageView profileImage;

        ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            messageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
            timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        }

        void bind(Messages message) {
            messageText.setText(message.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

and my `ChatActivity.java`

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View action_bar_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_custom_layout,null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(action_bar_view);


    mTitleView = findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_title);
    mLastSeenView = findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_seen);
    mProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.custom_appbar_image);
    mChatAddBtn = findViewById(R.id.chat_add_btn);
    mChatSendBtn = findViewById(R.id.chat_send_btn);
    mChatMessageView = findViewById(R.id.chat_message_view);

    mChatAddBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mChatAddBtn.setEnabled(false);

    mTitleView.setText(userName);


    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);

    mMessagesList = findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    mRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.message_swipe_layout);
    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);
    mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

  //  loadMessages();


    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).child("seen").setValue(true);

    loadMessages();
```

Comment: When you are reopening the activity, did you check if your getItemViewType is returning correct value?

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a functional [Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). However, you can take a look to see how the adapter and the holder class are created where such a problem does not exist.

Comment: @Seeker how do i do that

Comment: @Eric Well, you will have to debug or at least print some logs using android.util.Log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem in the code

```
if (from_user == (current_user_id)) {

    return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;

} else {

    return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
}
```

You are checking equivalency with **==**. This is not the right way of checking string equivalency. If you want to check equivalency you need to call **equals()** method of string as mentioned in below code.

```
if (from_user.equals(current_user_id)) {

return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;

} else {

return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
}
```

Try this. Hope this will help you.